# Laravel 5: Store & return multiple cached info in single request

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I separated large cached information into smaller pieces to be useful in multiple different requests rather than cache the whole response, my question is: Is there a way to save multiple info (multiple keys & values) in a single request rather than:

```
Cache::add('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

and return them in a single request too (different keys), rather than:

```
$value = Cache::get('key');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store single data with different names, but get a list with `$allData = Cache::many(['one', 'two', 'etc']);` - [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.html). Storing with similar `putMany`.

> many(array $keys)
>
> Retrieve multiple items from the cache by key.

You can extend `database` driver and create your own. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#writing-the-driver)

Comment: They're different data with different names

Comment: Well, that's why I've shown an example of getting three different data with names `one`, `two` and `etc`.

Comment: This sound Gr8 as doc, but for some reason I get `class 'Illuminate\Cache\DatabaseStore' does not have a method 'many'`

Comment: Well, some drivers like `file` and `database` don't support it as well as cache tags. Use memcached\redis\mongo.

Comment: I use `database`

Comment: Well, you can extend `database` driver by yourself and write your own method. Laravel docs has clear description how to create own cache driver.

Comment: Any link will be very helpful